# Read and parse all files inside S3 paths from Kafka with Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am reading the S3 url from a Kafka producer. Then going to that S3 url to process all files inside that folder. After grabbing the info from each file, I will pass that data to a sink.

Initially, I have a `DataStream<String>` that will read and grab the nested JSON value from the Kafka source's `ObjectNode`, using the `JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema`. So the path exists as a `String` inside the `DataStream`. How do I pass this string to a `FileSource`? The `FileSource` object takes in a `Path` object for the place of the folder.

I'm planning to use `FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat` to go through all the files and then all the lines of each file. However, this outputs a `FileSource<String>`, then a `DataStream<String>` by calling `env.fromSourced`.

The example I'm looking at now is: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/sideoutput/SideOutputExample.java

I see that `FileSource` takes in a `Path` object and then eventually gets a `DataStream<String>` but is there a way for me  to grab that `String` from the initial Kafka source `DataStream<String>` and then use it for a `FileSource`?

Comment: Where do you plan to run Flink? What you're trying to do does not seem to be straightforward and you might want to consider using other services together with Flink.

Comment: I'm running Flink inside an AWS EMR cluster. Flink will have a source from a Kafka topic, where the S3 path will come from. I want to go to that S3 path and parse all the files in that folder. The problem I have is getting that S3 path into a FileSource object.

I was thinking of creating my own SinkFunction and then access that SinkFunction's values but that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: In that case you could write a Flink job for S3 processing which takes S3 path as input parameter. For each Kafka event, you then trigger a new Flink job on EMR (with lambda or any other suitable service).

Comment: I can see how that works but unsure of the exact implementation.


I would have a DataStream<String> from the Kafka source but how would I pass that S3 path that's in that datastream to another flink job?

Comment: You would start new Flink jobs from AWS lambda or some other service, not from Flink (I guess you could also from Flink, it just seems like an overkill).